# Equivalent probability measures - integration

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P,Q$ be two equivalent probability measures on a probability space $(\Omega,A)$ and a given random variable $X$. Prove or find a counter-example: $X \in \mathcal{L}^1(P)$ implies $X \in \mathcal{L}^1(Q)$.

I think the assumption is false, but I am unable to find any counter-example.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Choose $X\geqslant0$ in $L^1(P)$ such that $E^P(X)=1$ and consider $dQ=XdP$. When is $X$ in $L^1(Q)$? If you can answer this, you have your counterexample...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's false. Any two measures with continuous nonzero densities are equivalent to eachother. So for example take $P$ to be gaussian measure and $Q$ to be Cauchy $\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ so that the former has a finite expectation but the latter does not